# Access gmail using imap with XOAUTH2 on production (JAVA)

Tags: oauth-2.0, imap

I implement a IMAP gmail client using Oauth 2.0 that work fine on development mode. I can connect to IMAP, search e-mails,  insert labels... but when I deploy my application, throw me an error here:

> IMAPStore store = OAuth2Authenticator.connectToImap("imap.gmail.com",
>   993, "user@email.com", oauth, true);

Error:

> Empty username or password. f5if721432qez.143

I use the same code of the examples of Google: http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode

Have to configure something else on production?